# Alinear imagenes con css

Tags: html5, css3

[image: imagen vista actual]Disculpen mi pregunta pero no consigo alinear de 3 en 3 las imágenes de mis productos ¿Me podrían  decir como es el código para lograr esto? Muchas gracias de antemano

```
@foreach($user as $us)                              
@foreach($us->productos as $prouser)

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-9 p-b-50">
    <!-- Product -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-b-50">
            <!-- Block2 -->
            <div class="block2">
                <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative " nombre="imagen" id="imagen">
            <img src="{{asset('imagenes/productos/'.$prouser->imagen)}}" alt="IMG-PRODUCT" >

            <div class="block2-overlay trans-0-4">
            <a href="#" class="block2-btn-addwishlist hov-pointer trans-0-4">
            <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart_alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart dis-none" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a> 
            <div class="block2-btn-addcart w-size1 trans-0-4">
            <!-- Button -->
            <a  class="flex-c-m size1 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4" href="{{route('cart-add',$prouser->idProducto)}}"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i>Agregar</a> 

    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="block2-txt p-t-20">
    <a href="{{URL::action('StoreController@show',$prouser->idProducto)}}" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5">
    {{$prouser->nombre}}
    </a>

    <span class="block2-price m-text6 p-r-5">
        Precio:${{number_format($prouser->costo_unitario,2)}}
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Quieres que las 3 imagenes esten al lado de las otras?

Comment: basicamente que 3 imagenes esten en horizontal y debajo otras 3 y asi consecutivamente

Comment: Estas usando bootstrap?

Comment: no , estoy utilizando css

Comment: Podrías publicar tu CSS.

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, por favor edita tu pregunta para añadir más información y código: especifica qué framework estás usando o  incluso mejor, comparte el HTML generado en lugar del código que lo genera. Además, debes compartir el CSS porque sin saber cuáles son tus estilos, es imposible saber qué es lo que hay que corregir. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.